# PHP como deletar arquivo .jpg de todas as pastas e subpastas possiveis

Tags: php

Atualmente consigo facilmente deletar arquivos de uma pasta com o código abaixo

```
array_map('unlink', glob($diretorio."*.jpg"));
```

Porem eu não consigo encontrar um meio de acessar possíveis subpastas, os nomes das subpastas e sua quantidade podem ser aleatório e imprevisível, como eu poderia criar um laço para percorrer todos os caminhos possíveis e ir deletando os arquivos desejados ?

Comment: Eu consigo fazer sem esforço com a classe [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php). Mas não sei se o uso de um iterador o serve.

Comment: No meu site o usuario sobre um .zip, eu faço a descompactação, porem sei que é possivel ter dentro do zip arquivos maliciosos, ou arquivos que não deveriam estar lá, 
Com o array_map('unlink', glob($diretorio."*.jpg")); eu romovo arquivos jpg apenas da pasta raiz, mas temo que os usuarios subam no zip sub pastas e dentro delas arquivos imprudentes por assim dizer>

eu precisaria de um meio de percorrer todas as subpastas possiveis e ir deletando arquivos .jpg por exemplo .

Comment: Encontrei maneiras de varrer a pasta principal, porem não consigo bolar um meio de acessar subpastas das quais não sei os nomes

Comment: Também é possível excluir diretamente no arquivo zipado, porém acredito ser o caso de fazer outra pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Alguns conceitos devem ser vistos.

> ### Iteradores recursivos e não recursivos
>
> O PHP possui iteradores não
> "recursivos", como `ArrayIterator` e `FilesystemIterator`. Existem também
> iteradores "recursivos", como o `RecursiveArrayIteratore`
> `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`. Os últimos têm métodos que os permitem
> aprofundar, os primeiros não.
>
> Quando as instâncias desses iteradores são executadas em loop por
> conta própria, mesmo os recursivos, os valores só vêm do nível
> "superior", mesmo que estejam em loop em uma matriz ou diretório
> aninhado com subdiretórios.
>
> <sub>Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235779/11379709</sub>

- Itere recursivamente nos diretórios do sistema de arquivos com a classe [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).
- Obtenha um iterador não recursivo que elenque todos os elementos de um iterador recursivo com [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).
- Para filtrar umiterador com base em uma expressão regular use [`RegexIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.regexiterator.php)
- Copie os elementos de um iterador em um array com a função [`iterator_to_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php)

```php
$diretorio = '.';        //Caminho do diretório a ser vasculhado.

//Obtém um iterador não recursivo que lista caminho dos arquivos do diretório 
//assim como os arquivos de seus subdiretórios.
$IteratorRecursivo = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($diretorio)
);

//Filtra os arquivos com extensão .jpg e cria um array com o caminho desses arquivos.
$Arquivos = array_keys(
  iterator_to_array(
      new RegexIterator(
         $IteratorRecursivo, '/^.+\.jpg$/i',
         RegexIterator::GET_MATCH
      )
  )
);

//Exclui os arquivos .jpg do diretórios e de seus subdiretórios.
array_map("unlink", $Arquivos);
```

Comment: Quem votou negativo poderia me ajudar e apontar aonde está o erro?